# Binding int property to bool UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following binding in XAML where `IsEnabled` is of type bool and `Length` is a property of Array that is of type int.

```
<Button
        Content="Press Me"
        IsEnabled="{Binding MyArray.Length, FallbackValue=False}">
</Button>
```

It does what I want it to, when the array length is 0 it disables, when the array contains elements it enables.

However, I didn't expect it to work, since you can't implicitly convert from int to bool in C#.

**Is this safe?**

Comment: It works means IsEnabled is set to false when the array is empty? Better use a binding converter.

Comment: Agree, use `IValueConverter` or have a property on the ViewModel return boolean based on the length of you array.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so you shouldn't rely on it.

A safe and simple solution would be a Style with a DataTrigger:

```
<Button Content="Press Me">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyArray.Length}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: What you say about it not being documented anywhere, is a very good reason for me to change it, thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this safe?

In short, yes it is safe - as you have a `FallbackValue`, if the binding fails.

---

**You could use a good ol' `DataTrigger`**
*I'd forgotten about them in WPF (I've been working on WinRT a lot recently - and they're not available in that)*

This will bind the trigger to the `Length` of your `MyArray`, and then when the condition is satisfied - set the `IsEnabled` property of the button to (in this case) `false`.

```
<Button Content="Press Me">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyArray.Length}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

---

**Bind to a `bool` on your ViewModel**

You could also use a `public bool` Property on your ViewModel, and then base your `IsEnabled` on this:

```
public bool IsEnabled { get { return MyArray.Length > 0; } }
```

and in your Xaml:

```
<Button
    Content="Press Me"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}}">
</Button>
```

---

**Use an `IValueConverter`**
*Best option for anyone using WinRT*

You could also create and use a `Converter` which can give back a `boolean` based on the condition you're after.

See http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html for a great tutorial on how to implement Converters into your WPF.

A converter implements `IValueConverter`, and would look something like this:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from bool to visibility
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from visibility to bool
    }
}
```

Don't forget to reference it in your user control/view - or even in your `App.xaml` in order to use it as a `StaticResource`.

**Examples?**

You could interpret your own converter any which way you want, based on your own logic.

In this case you could create a converter, and use it in the Xaml, like so:

You could create a `ArrayNotNullOrEmptyToBooleanConverter`, and use it in your Xaml like so:

```
<Button
    Content="Press Me"
    IsEnabled="{Binding MyArray, Converter={Binding ArrayNotNullOrEmptyToBooleanConverter}}">
</Button>
```

Or just simply create a `IsGreaterThanZeroToBooleanConverter` and then use that in your Xaml, like so:

```
<Button
    Content="Press Me"
    IsEnabled="{Binding MyArray.Length, Converter={Binding IsGreaterThanZeroToBooleanConverter}}">
</Button>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I guess the question is, why am I better creating a converter?

Comment: Completely my bad - I'd forgotten about ye olde `DataTrigger`s in WPF - I've updated my answer. At least you have a few suggestions to make a decision from :)

Comment: Nice that you plagiarized my answer.

Comment: Great, isn't it? :)

Comment: Don't worry @Clemens I saw you got there first ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I did not believe it would work but it does

Zero is false and everything else is true

All in can figure is that it treating it like a bit where zero is false and every other number is 1 and true.
That is how bit works in MS SQL Server.

I don't know that you could count on it in future versions of .NET.

I works even with a fallback
I tested on a TextBox
It is not even throwing a binding error
If I give it a bad name like iii is does throw a binding error
If you bind to a string it throws a binding error

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding ii}" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Text="TexBox" />

public int ii { get { return 0; } }
```

or you could just do this

```
 public bool iiEnabled { get { return arrayLength > 0; } }
```

Comment: Down vote did you test binding to an int.  It does work.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, either - but I agree with your theory. My thought was that it might be working using the `0` or `1` bit logic